# Common audio format for Android, iOS, Windows Phone

Tags: android, ios, audio, audio-recording

I need to produce an audio file on an Android device that can be played on any other Android, iOS, or Windows Phone device. I need to do this without any third party apps. I am using .NET on the server, so I could convert there but I'd like to avoid that. I can see that you can record AAC in 2.3.3, but I need to use 2.2. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the old .wav format should do the trick. It seems to be supported by both android and ios. I did not check wm7, but it is in wm6.5, so my guess is that it will be supported also:

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc907934.aspx

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html

Comment: so was my thinking about/ .wav file but when i try to play .wav file on my droid it fails saying "sorry, the player does not support this type of audio file".

Comment: @developer googleing around it seems to be an issue specific with the droids. Moreover, it looks like they lack support of GSM6.10/WAVE (and android specification does not ask for it). Make sure that your wav files are PCM/WAVE and not GSM.

Comment: WAV is just a wrapping format possibly containing one of hundreds of encodings (yes, even MPEG1 level 3 aka MP3). When suggesting WAV, people usually refer to plain PCM 16bit.

Comment: @Till yes, that was my point. In the links I posted above it clearly states support for PCM encoding. That *should* work in every device.

Comment: there must've been something wrong with the wav i had on my droid, because it seems to work right now just fine. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Mp3, and wav are both supported on absolutly every system, including ios, android, and windows 7 mobile. mp3 is generally used for music, but for just about anything else, it is generally standard to use wav.